# Building a Word Document in C# is stopping me from making panels visible in ASP, what's going wrong?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-word, panel, visible

So I'm working with this form which, at the end, generates a Word document for the user to download, fires off some emails, and then displays a success panel for the user. The problem I'm having is that the .Visible flags don't end up getting changed whenever I call the downloadWordFile() method. Is there something in that method that would be messing with my ability to change visibility of ASP panels? I've tried removing almost every part of this to see where the issue is popping up and I haven't been able to make heads or tails of it. Everything else works fine, it's just this method causing the issue. Thanks in advance for your help!

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        {
            pnlForm.Visible = false;
            pnlSuccess.Visible = true;
            email();
            adminEmail();
            downloadWordFile();
        }

protected void downloadWordFile(){
        Response.ContentType = "application/msword";
        Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.UnicodeEncoding.UTF8;
        Response.Charset = "UTF-8";

        Response.Write("<html xmlns:o='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40'>");
        Response.Write("<head>");
        Response.Write("<META HTTP-EQUIV=\"Content-Type\" CONTENT=\"\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\"\">");
        Response.Write("<meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document>");
        Response.Write("</head>");
        Response.Write("<body>");
        Response.Write("<div class=Section2>");

        Response.Write(buildForm());

        Response.Write("</body>");
        Response.Write("</html>");
        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + "Generic.doc");
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    }
```

EDIT 1: I ended up going a different route entirely. Rather than trying to switch panels, generate emails, and generate word files all in one go, I made the submit button switch the panels, and the success panel now shows a preview of the word document to be downloaded and provides the user a chance to make changes. There is a download button on the success panel that generates the emails and downloads the word document. This required minimal changes to the way the code was already set up and solved another problem I was having with the email generation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A response can only be one thing.  You can't respond with page content and a file.  You are setting the response to a file so that is how the browser handles the response.

I would handle this situation by the calling a JavaScript function in the button's click event that downloads the file via an IFrame.

First you would need a "download file" page.  In the `OnLoad` event of that page you can call `email();`, `adminEmail();` and `downloadWordFile();`

The JavaScript click event handler would look something like this.

```
function DownloadFile() {
    var downloadFrame = document.createElement("IFRAME");   

    if (downloadFrame != null) {
        downloadFrame.setAttribute("src", 'DownloadFile.aspx');
        downloadFrame.style.width = "0px";
        downloadFrame.style.height = "0px";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadFrame);

        //Set the visibility of pnlForm and pnlSuccess
    }
}
```

**EDIT:**
Per your comment, I've had to do the same thing.  I solved it by posting the form as normal and assembling the form values into a query string.  Then use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` to add a script that calls the `DownloadFile()` function when the page loads.  The `DownloadFile()` function takes the query string as a parameter and the `DownloadFile.aspx` page uses it to get the form data.

So the click event handler would be updated like this.

```
function DownloadFile(queryString) {
    var downloadFrame = document.createElement("IFRAME");   

    if (downloadFrame != null) {
        downloadFrame.setAttribute("src", 'DownloadFile.aspx' + queryString);
        downloadFrame.style.width = "0px";
        downloadFrame.style.height = "0px";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadFrame);

        //Set the visibility of pnlForm and pnlSuccess
    }
}
```

Comment: I think I can use this as a jumping off point, thanks! One of the problems with this method is that the word document being downloaded is generated from content entered on the form, so I have to pass all of the information from the form onto the new page, otherwise I'll get a bunch of "txtTitle does not exist in this context" type errors.

Comment: In response to your edit: Since I'm dealing with 60+ fields, rather than using query strings, is there any reason why I couldn't use an array to store the 60 fields and then read from the array rather than using a queryString, which would get pretty unwieldy at that size?

Comment: That's a big form.  I might consider using the browser's local storage to persist the form data.  Local storage is an HTML5 specification so browser compatibility might be an issue with that.

Comment: If you used an array, where would you store the array between requests?

Comment: I ended up going a different route entirely. Rather than trying to switch panels, generate emails, and generate word files all in one go, I made the submit button switch the panels, and the success panel now shows a preview of the word document to be downloaded and provides the user a chance to make changes. There is a download button on the success panel that generates the emails and downloads the word document. This required minimal changes to the way the code was already set up and solved another problem I was having with the email generation.